# Can't use JavaCV OpenCVFrameGrabber?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am really stuck on a project right now.  I have been struggling to find anything that will let me get frames from a video in Java.  Finally I found OpenCV which seemed very promising.  I can't figure out how to get it to work though.

I found another question where the asker posted this code:

```
OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("D:/2.avi");        
grabber.start();
IplImage frame = grabber.grab();
```

My problem is that I can't get OpenCVFrameGrabber to be recognized no matter what.  I have a tiny block of code set up as follows:

```
import org.opencv.*;

public class Hello {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("");
    }    
}
```

I am using Eclipse and as you can see I got to the point where I just imported the entire opencv library, but OpenCVFrameGrabber still can't be found.  I am really stuck and have no idea what to do to use the OpenCVFrameGrabber.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Libraries:** Have you imported the correct .jar file? Download the binaries from here, extract them and add them to your build path.

**2. Java import** The class `OpenCVFrameGrabber` is not located in the `org.opencv` package. It is located in `com.googlecode.javacv`.

So you have to make the following import:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make javacv work.

Download javacv bin package

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list

Extract it

Downlaod opencv associated with javacv release. See javacv README file.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/

For windows 8 I used opencv-win

Execute opencv exe and select c:\ as extract dir

In eclipse project add external jars: javacv.jar, javacpp.jar and javacv-windows-x86_64.jar from javacv-bin directory

I used this answer as reference
[Best way to access web camera in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487251/best-way-to-access-web-camera-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
```