# How to Capture photo from webcam in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, webcam, photo

I want to build a simple program using eclipse tool,
and in this program  I need to use webcam of the computer !
I just need a simple code to get the photo from a webcam 
Thanks for helping...

Comment: Sorry, but the code to get an image from a webcam is extremely complex and only for Java experts to use.

Comment: Maybe [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java?rq=1) helps. If not you will have to be a bit more specific in what you want and ,even better, show what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are invalid as they say it is "extremely hard". It was, still upto some level, but not that much.

1. If you are into Image Processing (process the image once you get the picture) then use `JavaCV`. It can access web cam. It is a wrapper to `OpenCV C++` Library so some setup might get invloved.
2. Do not try JMF, VLCJ, FMJ because they are all outdated.
3. Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487251/best-way-to-access-web-camera-in-java). Have a look at the answer with an image, It is a webcam project for Java, find the [GitHub project here](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture)