# how can I capture picture from digital camera through my pc in java

Tags: java, camera

I want to know that is there any `API` that support digital camera such as nikon coolpix, that the view captured from camera shown in window or applet and i capture image from that camera by keypress or button click. that camera can be connected by usb or in remote place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if the camera has a webcam mode.
If so, you can check this:

[Best way to access web camera in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487251/best-way-to-access-web-camera-in-java)