# How to read frames as jpeg stream from usb camera under windows

Tags: java, windows, camera

I have an usb camera device from which i wish to capture frames with 1920x1080px at 30 fps as jpeg stream.
I have tried various libraries to grab camera frames as jpeg stream (sarxos, openCV), but none of them seems to provide such functionality. The main problem is that these libraries are grabbing frames as uncompressed bitmap, which makes reading frames very slow for 1920x1080px frames (like 5 fps/sec). Multithreading doesn't help here and the fps seems limited by USB 2.0 transfer rate, which is around 30 MB/sec, whereas one uncompressed fullhd frame is around 6 MB. My understanding is that I need to read jpeg stream from the camera instead of uncompressed frames, but I didn't found any library capable of doing this. I know that it is possible since I've done this on linux using v4l4j, but now I need solution for windows.

The ideal solution would be to use java, but I'm unsure if there exists a java library capable of doing this under windows.

Any ideas for accomplishing this are more than welcomed.

I agree that this question falls a bit under the category of "recommend a software", but I just really need advice on how to do this, the subject isn't very popular and the research is hard, that's why I've decided to ask for help here. There's a big chance that someone have big experience with this subject and will exactly know how to accomplish this goal. I do also consider this question potentially very usefull for others as the subject of efficiently grabbing and processing high res images in java is growing in importance.

The camera model is misumi TD-B31105 from http://www.misumi.com.tw/PLIST.ASP?PC_ID=57.

Comment: Look at ffmpeg ))

Comment: many many ways --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487251/best-way-to-access-web-camera-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java ... I dont know what you are looking for-- fastness??? then probably ffmpeg will work